# Produto de Matrizes

Tags: java, matriz

Estou tentando criar um método que retorna o produto de duas matrizes passadas como parâmetro. O método está funcionando apenas para matrizes quadradas e não para duas matrizes 2x3 e 3x2, por exemplo. Se alguém puder ajudar e dizer onde está o erro, eu agradeço.

```
  public static int[][] calculaProduto(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int[][] result = new int[ a.length ][ b[0].length ];


    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
            int somatoria = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                // A: (0x0) * B:(0x0) + A:(0x1) * B:(1x0)...
                // 
                //

                int produto = a[j][k] * b[k][j];
                somatoria += produto;
                result[i][j] = somatoria;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro no teu código está na forma como indexas as matrizes. Experimenta assim:

```
public static int[][] calculaProduto(int[][] a, int[][] b) {

    if (a[0].length != b.length) throw new RuntimeException("Dimensões inconsistentes. Impossível multiplicar as matrizes");

    int[][] result = new int[ a.length ][ b[0].length ];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
            int somatoria = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++) {
                int produto = a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                somatoria += produto;
            }
            results[i][j] = somatoria ;
        }
    return result ;
}
```

Podes simplificar o código um pouco e remover as variáveis `somatoria` e `produto`. Ficaria assim:

```
public static int[][] calculaProduto(int[][] a, int[][] b) {

    if (a[0].length != b.length) throw new RuntimeException("Dimensões inconsistentes. Impossível multiplicar as matrizes");

    int[][] result = new int[ a.length ][ b[0].length ];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) 
            for (int k = 0; k < a[0].length; k++) 
                results[i][j] += (a[i][k] * b[k][j]);
    return result ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Meu deu certo, só ñ sei c é o melhor possível

```
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        int linha = 1;
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            linha *= ma[i][j];
        }
        for(z=0;z<4;z++){
            int col = 1;
            for(l=0;l<4;l++){
                col *= ma[i][j];
            }
            prod[i][z] = col + linha;
        }
    }
```